# What is it about Float32Array that prevents changing the contents after it is created?

Tags: javascript

Simple program to demonstrate problem. It's a simple program to demonstrate a simple problem.

```js
var dogbutt = []; // Create an array
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
  dogbutt[i] = .04 * i; // Fill it with numbers

console.log(dogbutt);

var vertexArray = Float32Array.from(dogbutt); // Create a 2nd array
console.log(vertexArray);

for (i = 0; i < vertexArray.last; i++)
  vertexArray[i] = 0.1 * i; // Fill 2nd array with different numbers

console.log(vertexArray); // Nothing has changed
```

```html
Float32Array unexpected behavior
```

Comment: I can't see a `last` property on `Float32Array` prototype? Try using `vertexArray.length`?

Comment: That explains the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Just checking, but do you understand why the loop didn't run?

Comment: Yes, I understand. Javascript is stupid and uncooperative and should be sent to reeducation camp. Any smart language would have realized that in this context 'last' and 'length' mean the same thing.

Comment: sorry I didn’t mean to sound patronising. I also don’t know of any other language that would do what you’ve described...

Comment: It was a joke. All programming languages are stupid, but that is how you exert precise control. If they were smart, who knows what they might do?

Comment: ah I see. /r/woosh